# What is the difference between different ways of attaching\detaching event handlers in C#

Tags: c#, events, delegates

There are two parts to my question -

Firstly we can attach event handlers in following two ways -

```
myObject.MyEvent += new EventHandler(MyHandler);

myObject.MyEvent += MyHandler;
```

As per my understanding these two are equivalent. In the second case the C# compiler does the job of creating a delegate instance from the appropriate overload from the specified method group. Is this correct?

Secondly, is there any difference between the two corresponding styles of detaching the handler? If yes then what is it?

```
 myObject.MyEvent -= new EventHandler(MyHandler);

 myObject.MyEvent -= MyHandler;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference in the IL code that is generated - as you mentioned. C# compiler creates a handler anyway.

In the removing also, there is no difference.

Answer (score 5):

They are identical, unless you are in c# 1.2 where only the first compiles.