# What is the difference between these two syntaxes for hooking up an event handler?

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an actual difference in the 2 different ways of attaching event handlers in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214346/is-there-an-actual-difference-in-the-2-different-ways-of-attaching-event-handlers)

I've been seeing a lot of code that looks like this:

```
foo.Drop += new DragEventHandler(fooHandler);
```

But in the past, I've always done this:

```
foo.Drop += fooHandler;
```

Is there a difference between these two syntaxes? If so, is there any advantage to doing it the long way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an actual difference in the 2 different ways of attaching event handlers in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214346/is-there-an-actual-difference-in-the-2-different-ways-of-attaching-event-handlers), [What is the difference between Events with Delegate Handlers and those without?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119160/what-is-the-difference-between-events-with-delegate-handlers-and-those-without), [What is the difference between different ways of attaching\detaching event handlers in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360451/)

Comment: Definitely a duplicate. Voted to close myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second is shorthand for the first; they will compile to indentical IL.

However, the second syntax is new to C# 2.0; C# 1 only supports the first.

Answer (score 2):

They will both result in the same [IL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language).

So, in answer to your question, no - there is no benefit of using the longer version.

Comment: You linked to a disambiguation page that suggests MSIL is the "former acronym" of what is now called [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language).

Comment: @Cody Gray updated to the more direct link

Comment: I assume it comes from the effort to emphasize that the platform is not fully proprietary. Microsoft has been somewhat encouraging at various times to efforts like the Mono Project. Everyone I know just calls it "IL", myself included. Prevents marketing from interfering with understanding. ;-)

Comment: Good spot - thanks.  Answer updated to call it "IL" ;)

Answer (score 0):

No difference , since .Net 2 and you can use what is called Method Group Conversion which allow you to Register the method name directly to the event without making a delegate Object

Answer (score 0):

They are the same, but in the second example, the compiler uses Method Group conversion to infer the delegate type for you. Syntactic sugar...